# SASS combine multiple classes from vuetify's flex utilities

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

Scattered around my code I have the classes `d-md-flex flex-md-row flex-wrap` always called together. Ideally, I would like to combine these into one class called `mobile-row`.

For example instead of having

```html
<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-row flex-wrap"> ... </div>
```

I would have

```html
<div class="mobile-row"> ... </div>
```

In my sass code, I tried to combine the classes together using `@extend`

```js
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass'
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'

.mobile-row
    @extend .d-flex, .flex-md-row, .flex-wrap
```

It seems to work, but the styling is vastly different. All the gutters are gone, and the size of all the elements shrunk drastically.

For example, here is the output on a screen for the medium breakpoint.  Where the expected result is from adding the classes directly to the `div` tag, and the result is from the compiled sass.

[image: Results]

Is there a way to do what I am trying to accomplish? Am I approaching this the wrong way? Or is this just a foolish effort?